# Forster exercise 17.3 on Riemann-Roch theorem

Tags: complex-analysis, algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

Let $X$ Riemann Surface of genus $g$, and $D$ is a divisor on $X$. I try to prove $l(D)=dim H^0 (X,O_D) ≤ 1+degD$ when $−1≤degD≤g−1$ Using the Riemann-Roch theorem and Serre duality. The notations here : $H^0(X,O_D)$ is obviously the $0$-th cohomology group of $X$ with respect to the sheaf $O_D$ where $O_D(U)=\{f∈\mathcal{M}(U)|ordx(f)≥−D(x)∀x∈U\}$ and $\mathcal{M}$ is the sheaf of meromorphic functions.

The statement of Riemann-Roch in O.Forster Book is : for a compact Riemann surface $X$ of genus $g$ and a divisor $D$ on it, $$dimH^0(X,O_D)−dimH^1(X,O^D)=1−g+degD.$$

I tried to use the Serre duality which asserts that $dimH^1(X,O_D)=dimH^0(X,Ω_{−D})$ where $Ω_{−D}$ is the sheaf of meromorphic $1$-forms that are multiples of $−D$. Or, use the the exact sequenece
$$0\to H^0(X,D−p)→H^0(X,D)→\mathbb{C}→0.$$ I find that, if $D=P-N$, where $P,N$ two effective divisors, then $l(D)≤ 1+deg(P)$. But i cannot find the finale result.

Could I please get a hint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $D$ is not effective, $h^0(X,D) = 0$, so we can assume $D$ effective. By Riemann-Roch and Serre duality,

$$
h^0(X,D) = 1 + \deg(D) - g + h^0(X, \Omega_{-D})
$$

The inequality follows if $h^0(X, \Omega_{-D}) \le g$. But $h^0(X, \Omega) = g$ in the first place, and imposing zeroes (twisting *down* by $D$ effective) can only decrease $h^0$.

Comment: I have q question, what's mean effictive for you? It's juste mean positive divisor? for example $D=3P-3Q$ its not positive or negative but the inequalitie holde in elliptic curves. If $D$ is non negative, its mean $\Omega_{-D} (X) \subset \Omega(X)$ ? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, an effective divisor, denoted symbolically as $D\ge 0$, is one whose coefficients are all $\ge 0$. The key implication of this is that sections of $O_D$ differ from sections of $O$ only in that some poles are allowed, as opposed to when $D$ has negative coefficients and hence imposes zeroes on sections of $O_D$. Anyway, I was not asserting that the inequality cannot hold for non-effective divisors, just that I can only guarantee that it will hold for all effective divisors. As to your last question, yes: if $D \ge 0$, $\Omega_{-D}$ is the subspace of holomorphic forms vanishing along $D$.

Comment: Thanks, I understand now ..

Answer (score 1):

If $D$ is non-negative ok, if not just change $D$ by $D'=div(f)+D$ where $f\in O_D$, then $l(D)=l(D')\leq 1+deg(D')=1+deg(D)$.

rmk$_1$: If $D$ and $D'$ are equivalent divisors on Riemann Surfaces then $O_D(X)\simeq O_{D'}(X)$ given by multiplication of a meromorphic function on $X$.

rmk$_2$: $div(f)$ is the divisor associated a meromorphic function, then $deg(div(f))=0$ (The degree of a holomorphic map is constant in the set of regular values).

Comment: I understand, Thank you very much !